# How can I control UTF-8 ordering in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, utf-8, collation

For example, this is the order that a standard 'SORT BY name' query is returning:

```
name
------
Cebbb
Čebbc
Cebbd
```

I'd like to SORT BY name and get the accented character *first*, grouped with other accented characters, e.g.

```
name
------
Čebbc
Cebbb
Cebbd
```

By default, MySql treats `Č` as if it were `C`, for sorting purposes, and sorts in the order shown.

Alternatively, is there a way, in PHP, that I can 'convert' `Č` to `C`, for comparison purposes?

Answer (score 10):

You can [add a `COLLATE` expression to your `ORDER BY` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html):

```
SELECT k
FROM t1
ORDER BY k COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Then, the column will be sorted using the correct collate, and the column definition can stay as it is.

Comment: I think the original question was confusing; I've updated to clarify.

Comment: Yogu's solution seems to answer your question though. With the correct collation, SQL will sort the characters in whatever the correct order is for that language.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to apply a proper collation to the column itself, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`foo_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

---

**Update:**

[Č](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8C#Uses) isn't a Spanish letter:

> In Croatian, Slovenian, Bosnian, Skolt Sami, and Lakota alphabets, it
>   is the **fourth letter** of the alphabet. In Czech, Northern Sámi alphabet
>   and the Baltic languages Lithuanian and Latvian, the letter is in
>   **fifth place**. In Slovak it is **sixth letter** of the alphabet. It is also
>   used in Pashto (equivalent to چ‎) and Saanich.

Unlike numbers, letters don't have a fixed absolute order. The whole concept of alphabetic order is relative—you have to pick a rule set first. Run this SQL query to know which ones are available in your MySQL server:

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET
```

... and chose the one that better fits your expectations. There's a [brief description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html) in the manual.

Comment: When you say 'proper', does that include utf8_general_ci? That's what the table and column is already specified as, and it's not going to be incredibly easy to change that, since the database isn't 'mine' (it's one provided by joomla)

Comment: "Proper" depends on the language. There're different rules when sorting text. If `utf8_spanish_ci` is your current collation, what's your exact problem? You don't want modern Spanish rules or you don't get them?

Comment: Ah - I see the problem. Are you saying that Č is a Spanish character? In this context, it actually isn't (or isn't being used in Spanish), but - I'm hoping - this isn't relevant. There will be a whole bunch of characters from several languages. If it's nonsensical to try to treat Č as C, then I'm happy *not* to, but this returns to the original problem that MySQL *is* treating them as equal.

Comment: @BobbyJack Then use `utf8_bin`. it compares characters by their Unicode code point, which means there's no accent or case folding.

Answer (score 0):

To replace special characters like those with accents or umlauts by ordinary latin characters, you can use the php function [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php):

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text)
```

This will convert the variable `$text` into pure ASCII characters. For example, *müßig* would be converted into *muessig*, and *caffée* into *caffee*.

Comment: although I don't know how the *alternative* solution is related to your main question

Comment: The alternative solution would allow me to treat the two characters as the same in PHP, enabling me to group them under a common header. I'm getting rows from the DB, then outputting a 'header' when the initial character changes - like an index listing in a book. Currently, I'm getting a list of 'C' names, followed by a 'Č' name, followed by another list of 'C' names.

Comment: Ah ok, then the php solution seems to be the better one, because you surely don't want a section for each special character.

Comment: This is definitely the closest solution. Due to local environment issues (i.e. problems with iconv and MAMP), I can't actually use this solution immediately, but iconv() definitely solves the comparison problem. A MySql SORT BY fix would be even better, but I'm up-voting you in the meantime.

Comment: special characters are the exception, so a section per-special character would actually be OK.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's *my* solution to what is, admittedly, quite a special-case:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1),
         BINARY SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1),
         name
```

That's certainly not the most efficient query - in this case, though, that's not too big a concern - but it *does* solve my problem by:

1. Ordering by the initial character (in which MySql will treat `Č` and `C` as identical)
2. *Then* ordering by the binary value of the initial character, which will differentiate `Č` and `C`
3. *Then* ordering by the full name, which will - in effect - order by the rest of the string.

This will order non-optimally after the first character, but that's not a concern.